# Account Locks - Set Higher Number of Authentication Attempts from Specific IP Address

Tags: active-directory

Is there a way to change some setting in Active Directory that would allow requests coming from a certain IP address to make multiple incorrect LDAP requests without locking the account?

We currently have AD set up to lock accounts after 3 incorrect authentication attempts. I would like to either increase this number for requests coming from a certain IP address or turn off account locking altogether from this IP address.

It could also work if I could have AD ignore requests from a certain IP after several attempts and not lock the account.

Basically, we have a new self-service account unlocking tool that I would like to put on the Internet so accounts can be unlocked without being in our office. The only problem with the tool has a a login screen for managing security questions. This login screen can lock accounts, and I don't want it to be used to maliciously lock accounts. That's why I was hoping this could be done by IP address.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Account lockout is an attribute of the user account, not the computer account.

Comment: I think the best you could do would be a script to reset the `badpasswordcount` if source == $[desired ip], though I haven't tried such a thing or know what exciting new messes that would cause...

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the lockout policy based on the client IP. You can change the lockout policy by user, however. Bascially, you create a GPO with different lockout policies, then assign it to that user or OU. This will over-ride policies assigned higher up.

This is described here: [Can I prevent an Active Directory account from locking out?](https://serverfault.com/questions/247851/can-i-prevent-an-active-directory-account-from-locking-out)

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for. Basically, we have a new self-service account unlocking tool that I would like to put on the Internet so accounts can be unlocked without being in our office. The only problem with the tool has a a login screen for managing security questions. This login screen can lock accounts, and I don't want it to be used to maliciously lock accounts. That's why I was hoping this could be done by IP address.

Comment: Thank,s for the suggestion though.

Comment: In light of this new information, this is a TERRIBLE idea! You WANT the account to be locked out if someone hammers at the security questions.

Comment: They wouldn't be hammering at the security questions. They would be hammering at getting in. I was primarily concerned about an ex employee that knew usernames and knew they could lock the account on purpose.

Comment: Oh, I misread that part. It's a page where the users can log in with their password. Well, I still think this is a TERRIBLE idea. You will have a place where users can go to repeatedly guess a password with no lockout. That's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Good point. Just trying to figure out how to get out of having to VPN in to unlock accounts after hours.

Comment: What about setting up a two factor authentication method to access the account unlock web page?